# Define a variable in a shell script

Tags: bash, scripts

Yes, there are plenty of manuals on how to set variables in a script.
But I want to define a variable on script startup.
For example, I wish to display on script startup that file, which is `x` hours later - `script.sh hours=2` . So I open the file which is with date 2 hours later.

Here is the script:

```
NOW=$(date -d "1 hour" '+%Y.%m.%d-%H.00.00_*.00.00.txt' )
echo "**************"
cat /air/playlists/$NOW |grep servers2
```

I tried it with `read varname`, but it's not working.
Can anybody help?

Comment: Your script lacks a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

Comment: *but its not working....* what isn't working? are there any errors? how are you starting the script? is that the full script? Have you considered passing in parameters?

Comment: with this, its showing next hours file, when changing to:

Comment: O, upss, don.t know how its happened, but axidentetally got it working. Someone can edit this script and save for future.  echo Hello, how many hours forward?
read var
NOW=$(date -d "$var hour" '+%Y.%m.%d-%H.00.00_*.00.00.txt' )
echo "**************"
cat /air/playlists/$NOW |grep servers2

Comment: sorryt can.t edit as code.

Comment: echo Hello, how many hours forward?
read var
NOW=$(date -d "$var hour" '+%Y.%m.%d-%H.00.00_*.00.00.txt' )
echo "**************"
cat /air/playlists/$NOW |grep servers2

Comment: @saltolenin You can use markdown in your comments as well. When writing code, use back ticks to help make it readable (Top left side of US keyboard, Same key as tilde "~").  use three back ticks before and after the code ```NOW=$(date -d "$var hour" '+%Y.%m.%d-%H.00.00_*.00.00.txt' ) echo "**************" cat /air/playlists/$NOW |grep servers2```

Comment: Code in comments is awful to decipher. Editing your question above is much preferred.

Comment: @saltolenin After you click edit to edit your question, FIRST: put your cursor at the end of your question and then press enter to leave one blank line. THEN: paste the code. FINALLY: highlight or select the code and then press CTRL+K to automatically format it as code. It is quite simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here you have something to build on.

```
#!/bin/bash

a=/air/playlists

while true; do
    read -r -p "Hello, how many hours forward? " b
    b=${b:-0}
    if [[ ! $b =~ [0-9]+ ]]; then
        continue
    fi
    c=$(date -d "$b hour" "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.00.00_*.00.00.txt")
    echo -e $_{0..20}\\b*
    [[ -e $(echo $a/$c) ]] && { grep -e 'servers2' $a/$c; } || echo "Error file not found..."
    continue
done
```